# Pantone-like color matching for latex 6-color printing?

Tags: cmyk, color-profile, pantone, color-reproduction, latex

For print design with 4-color process, I've used the coated version of the Pantone Color Bridge to select colors.

I'd like to select similar, perhaps wider-gamut equivalent colors to be printed on latex with a 6-color CcMmYK/CMYKLcLm process. Is a latex inkjet printer going to produce colors more like the spot or process colors in my Pantone guide? Is 6-color going to increase the gamut or just reduce the halftone pattern?

Is there a better workflow or guide offered by Pantone or another company for seeing swatches of output colors as produced by a latex printer?

Comment: This particular pattern probably increases it a bit but mainly reduces the halftone. But then the latex we have does have a pretty wide gamut, though nothing compared to the better inkjets.

Answer (score 1):

Imho, your best bet is to make some tests. Send a small size file, let's say an A4 or letter sized file with some swatches, In RGB, in CMYK, and in spot colors and compare them.

If you can try to use at least Adobe 1998 color space, or ProPhoto RGB one.

Regarding the gamut, no, a 6 ink printer will not increase it, because the gamut is defined by the more saturated inks, in this case, the CMY ones. The lighter ones, Lc and Lm are to reduce the pattern on the light areas, where our eyes are more sensitive to see small dots over a light area.

It is not likely to produce a halftone at all, unless the printer is set to emulate some offset printing.